# function reading JSON data not passing to variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am creating a function to read different JSON files. The problem is when I try to pass the array.
I keep getting 'undefined' once I am back to my primary function. 
Reading the file works but when I try to use the variable I get 'undefined'.
I could use some help. thanks.

This is the file I read 'data.json':

```
[
    {
        "code":"10000",
        "name":"new",
        "filter":"Office",
        "label":"NEW"
    },
    {
        "code":"10001",
        "name":"classic",
        "filter":"Office",
        "label":"CLASSIC"
    },
    {
        "code":"10002",
        "name":"old",
        "filter":"Office",
        "label":"OLD"
    }
]
```

Here's my code:

```javascript
function readfile(myfile) {

    var mydata;

    $.get(myfile, function (data) {

        mydata = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(mydata); // result ok

    });
    console.log(mydata); // undefined

    return (mydata); // return  'undefined'
}

var content = readfile('data.json'); //should be an array

console.log(content); // undefined
```

Comment: mydata is not set when you get to console.log(mydata) because it is ran before the HTTPRequest finishes.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there!

The jQuery `$.get()` method is an asynchronous call. That means that instead of making the request to get `myfile`, waiting until it is complete, and then continuing from there, the code will make the request and continue on while the request is done in the background.

There are two things you can do here.

The first thing you can do is simply move your logic inside the callback function like so

```
$.get(myfile, function (data) {
    mydata = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(mydata); // do whatever you need 
});
```

However, if you want to continue using the `readfile` method, you can make the $.get request synchronous, wait for the response, then return from it.

Like so:

```
function readfile(myfile) {
   var mydata; 
   $.get({
        url: myfile,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            mydata = data;
        }
   });
   return mydata;
}
```

Comment: works with the request synchronous. thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Magens No problem! Glad I could help. Feel free to accept this answer if it was correct!

Answer (score 1):

Get is asynchronous meaning that it will not execute in the order it is written.

```
$.get(myfile, function (data) {

    mydata = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(mydata);              // result ok

});
```

This is why

```
console.log(mydata);                 // undefined

return (mydata);
```

is undefined, because the values are not actually set from get().

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize it was asynchronous.